# Where can I go for hands-on cocoa training besides WWDC?

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, cocoa-touch

I'm banging my head up against Cocoa and Xcode, and have been for months. I never seem to be able to get away from the tutorials, which are often incomplete, or Apple developer documentation, which is sparse on samples. I've watched videos, downloaded source code and asked developers for help. I still feel like I haven't gotten that audible "click" when something falls into place. Maybe I'm too old to learn something new, but I feel pretty productive in .Net!

Are there in-person training programs offered for Cocoa programming? Are there any resources I'm missing? User groups I don't know about?

I'm in Dallas, TX, but would be willing to fly anywhere in the US to get some real training!

EDIT 1:

The biggest problem I'm having is in the bindings between Interface Builder and XCode. I don't want to lose the productivity benefits of IB, but am stuck following step-by-step instructions to use a GUI tool. The nomenclature ("File's Owner", "Reference Outlet") is alien to me and I'd love someone who could literally sit down with me and explain step-by-step what I'm doing and why. I feel like I'm constantly cargo-culting and in between every time I sit down at my Mac I leak back out everything I've learned.

Comment: The interface between IB and Objective-C is where I have my trouble too. I forget to connect a dot or click a checkbox, and nothing works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Big Nerd Ranch.](http://www.bignerdranch.com/index.shtml)

> Big Nerd Ranch offers intensive,
>   head-down computer programming courses
>   taught by experts in a retreat
>   environment. Classroom,
>   accommodations, and dining all take
>   place within the same building,
>   freeing you to learn, code, and
>   discuss with your programming peers
>   and instructors. At Big Nerd Ranch, we
>   take care of the details; your only
>   job is to learn.

It's pricey, but worth it.

Comment: Not to mention the author of the best cocoa books out there, Aaron Hilegass works there.

Answer (score 1):

> The biggest problem I'm having is in
>   the bindings between Interface Builder
>   and XCode. I don't want to lose the
>   productivity benefits of IB, but am
>   stuck following step-by-step
>   instructions to use a GUI tool

I think you should ask your self if, right now, for you, IB is a productivity gain. I found that leaving IB well alone, and making UI's in code allowed me to learn much more about UIKit and how it worked. Then when I tried IB again, it was much clearer.

I would also recommend going to WWDC where you can speak to Apple engineers or lots of peer UIKit programmers.

With respect to your question about File's Owner it is a placeholder within the NIB for an object that exists in your app (i.e. not in the NIB) but which you pass in when you load the NIB. It's just "another object". You set it using the second parameter of NSBundle's `loadNibNamed:owner:options:`.

Answer (score 1):

Aaron Hillegass, who runs Big Nerd Ranch, has a book called '[Cocoa Programming for Mac OSX](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321774086),' now in its fourth edition, that covers everything you describe in a more hand-holdy way than the Apple documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to follow along with the new Stanford iPhone class:

http://news.stanford.edu/pr/2009/pr-apple-040109.html

It may help to edit your question to describe what seems to be the biggest roadblock - Objectve-C?  Cocoa?  IB?  XCode itself?

Answer (score 0):

Big Nerd Ranch is the most famous training "school" for Cocoa and Cocoa-Touch, but there are many others.

However, my friend, I feel that it is not Training per se that you need - I have a feeling that you're trying to follow intuition you got from .Net and other things you worked with, in Cocoa and that is usually painfully frustrating and non-productive. You see - These eco-systems have very little in common, and they hold big ideas of separate minds.

What I'd recommend is to "get the audible click" first, in just tiny samples you work on, and indeed ask people/google/stack-overflow questions. Learn the structure of Apple documentation, and above all STOP RELYING ON COPY&PASTE for development. You rarely develop any understanding from sample code. It is there for the last details, the correct parameters, the tried-and-works implementations. Never for learning the concepts.

Now I'm here (and many others too - better than myself) ready to answer any question we can.

Ah - a good book can be helpful too. I'm recommending Aaron Hillegass (Big Nerd Ranch) "Cocoa Programming for Mac OS-X". It gives real deep understanding, beside going from sample to sample.